# Can the 80K-15 high-voltage probe tip be unscrewed?

Tags: high-voltage, probe

Can the tip of the [80K-15 high-voltage probe](https://dam-assets.fluke.com/s3fs-public/80k15___iseng0100.pdf?qZFqFFQrabT8PQsRq2WXfrvpxNvdyg4e) (that I consider buying) be unscrewed? The datasheet does not say anything about this. I would like to unscrew the tip and make another one that can be clipped onto a wire or a pin, freeing my hands for longer measurements. No such hooks or clips seem to be provided either.

Comment: Why can't you make something that fastens to the probe tip?

Comment: @Andy aka: I think I can but screwing a something into the probe looks more elegant and the fastening would possibly be more firm.

Comment: A clipping tip attachment is dangerous because now you're reaching near the end of the probe to manipulate the clip. The probe is big huge and long with a shield for a reason. The datasheet does say it has no user serviceable parts and it certainly doesn't look like it can be unscrewed in close up photos. But in any case, a clipping tip is dangerous. Just a solid hook, not so much...probably.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about that exact one, but I have a Fluke 80K-40 probe and the tip indeed unscrews. It's aluminum and the thread appears to be #6-32 UNC.

[image]

Nothing one couldn't make in a few minutes on a metal turning lathe.

The tip sure looks the same on the [lower voltage one](https://www.tenaquip.com/product/fluke-80k-15-high-voltage-probe-80k-15-ib219?gclid=CjwKCAjwhNWZBhB_EiwAPzlhNjPwHvWhDiFhSqBUq205paZgU-UraKxWrSMtaQRAzLQh_Qesp7M21BoCDvUQAvD_BwE):

[image]